# python pandas. How to update the extraction results of a specific row to other columns of the original specific row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data as follows:

```
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
data = [["xxxx【A001-01】", "A001-01"],
        ["xxxx【A002】",    ""],
        ["xxxx【A003-01】", "A003-01"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=['A','B'])
df

out[1]:
                 A        B
0   xxxx【A001-01】   A001-01
1   xxxx【A002】  
2   xxxx【A003-01】   A003-01
```

I tried, but didn't succeed:

```
df.loc[df['B'] == ""]["B"] = df.loc[df['B'] == ""]["A"].str.extract(r"(【[A-Z][0-9]+】)",expand=True).replace("【", "",regex=True).replace("】", "",regex=True)
```

I hope to get the following results:

```
out[1]:
                 A        B
0   xxxx【A001-01】   A001-01
1   xxxx【A002】      A002
2   xxxx【A003-01】   A003-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change regex pattern for extract values between `【】`, only once create boolean mask `m` and last use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select by mask and column:

```
m = df['B'] == ""
df.loc[m, "B"] = df.loc[m,"A"].str.extract(r"【([A-Z][0-9]+)】",expand=False)

print (df)
               A        B
0  xxxx【A001-01】  A001-01
1     xxxx【A002】     A002
2  xxxx【A003-01】  A003-01
```